# failed to replace tabulator in list elements

Tags: python, replace

I wanted to replace the tabulator in my results, which was generated and captured by stdout and split into pieces of strings as shown below

the code used to format the results:

```
Text_formatted = [text.strip() for text in prozess.stdout.split('\n')]
```

Results are shown in the terminal:

> ['This is cutadapt 3.4 with Python 3.9.7', 'Command line parameters:
> --cores=8 -g TAGACATTAAAACTCATGATGGATG...AAAAGRAAGGTATGTGCATCTTA -o 1--2.CA.fasta S1--1.QC.fasta --discard-untrimmed', 'Processing
> reads on 8 cores in single-end mode ...', 'Finished in 0.81 s (4
> µs/read; 13.75 M reads/minute).', '', '=== Summary ===', '', 'Total
> reads processed:                 185,957', 'Reads with adapters:
> 72,274 (38.9%)', 'Reads written (passing filters):        72,274
> (38.9%)', '', 'Total basepairs processed:    25,596,106 bp', 'Total
> written (filtered):      6,938,162 bp (27.1%)', '', '=== Adapter 3
> ===', '', "Sequence: TAGACATTAAAACTCATGATGGATG...AAAAGRAAGGTATGTGCATCTTA; Type: linked;
> Length: 25+23; 5' trimmed: 72274 times; 3' trimmed: 72274 times", '',
> '', 'No. of allowed errors:', '1-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-25 bp: 2',
> '', 'No. of allowed errors:', '1-9 bp: 0; 10-19 bp: 1; 20-23 bp: 2',
> '', "Overview of removed sequences at 5' end",
> 'length\tcount\texpect\tmax.err\terror counts', '4\t12\t726.4\t0\t12',
> '5\t250\t181.6\t0\t250', '18\t1\t0.0\t1\t1', '21\t3\t0.0\t2\t1 1 1',
> '22\t2\t0.0\t2\t0 0 2', '23\t239\t0.0\t2\t7 10 222',
> '24\t3304\t0.0\t2\t77 3023 204', '25\t67555\t0.0\t2\t66919 592 44',
> '26\t895\t0.0\t2\t197 677 21', '27\t13\t0.0\t2\t0 5 8', '', '', '',
> "Overview of removed sequences at 3' end",
> 'length\tcount\texpect\tmax.err\terror counts', '17\t1\t0.0\t1\t1',
> '18\t1\t0.0\t1\t1', '19\t5\t0.0\t1\t4 0 1', '20\t12\t0.0\t2\t2 8 2',
> '21\t71\t0.0\t2\t3 5 63', '22\t1471\t0.0\t2\t51 1397 23',
> '23\t69654\t0.0\t2\t68917 712 25', '24\t181\t0.0\t2\t29 151 1',
> '27\t4\t0.0\t2\t4', '28\t449\t0.0\t2\t423 22 4', '29\t166\t0.0\t2\t148
> 15 3', '30\t237\t0.0\t2\t186 47 4', '31\t22\t0.0\t2\t21 1', '']

But when I used the following code to replace:

```
for i in Text_formatted:
        i.replace("\t"," ")
```

It generates, however the same outputs as before. So where could the problem lie on?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the value of the variable you are replacing:

```
Text_formatted = [text.strip() for text in prozess.stdout.split('\n')]

for i in range(len(Text_formatted)):
  Text_formatted[i] = Text_formatted[i].replace("\t", "")
```

Comment: it works, thanks. but replace would not work in-place, or an argument could be specified to make it in-place change?

Comment: @citron You mean `Text_formatted[i].replace("\t", "")` without the assignment?

Comment: yes, would it be possible?

Comment: @citron I tried it and it doesn't traverse correctly the list

Answer (score 0):

I think `i` iterate through all your letter one by one. So `i` will never be equal to `\t` because it's two char. Try to use replace directly on your Text_formatted : `Text_formatted.replace('\t',' ')`

Comment: Text_formatted is however a list object, so I cannot apply replace on it. :(